# NodeJS AWS S3 Proxy sometimes hangs - Restart Helps

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to proxy Amazon S3 files using NodeJS, and sometimes it works great, but other times it just hangs until the connection times out. I thought maybe S3 was rate limiting the requests, but restarting the server fixes it immediately.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

var proxy = function(req, res) {
        var filename = "testfile.mp4";
        var params = {Bucket: 'my-bucket', Key: filename};
        res.setHeader('content-type', 'video/mp4');
        s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(res);
    });
};
```

Comment: There's no documented rate limiting on S3.  "sudo apt-get install tshark" and you should be able to find out what's breaking down... it's a console-based protocol analyzer.